# How to insert a template-ref in other component dynamically angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to create a template(a piece of html code) somewhere else and then put that template code to some target component dynamically.

For example: Suppose I have created a template which is created in `other-component`

**other.component.html**

```html
<ng-template #source>
      some code here....
</ng-template>
```

Now I want to insert this template into `target-component` from its controller.

**target.component.html**

```html
<ng-content #target>
      to be inserted here....
</ng-content>
```

**target.component.js**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-target',
    templateUrl: './target.component.html'
})
export class TargetComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    private _config: Config;

    @Input()
    get hmConfig(): Config {
        return this._config;
    }
    set hmConfig(v: Config) {
        this._config = v;
        if (v.sourceTemplate && this.targetContainer) {
            this.targetContainer.createEmbeddedView(v.sourceTemplate);
        }
    }

    @ContentChild('target') targetContainer;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // output: After Modal view init: undefined
        console.log('After Modal view init: ', this.targetContainer);
    }

}
```

But above piece of code doesn't work, the reference to target `targetContainer` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by `*ngTemplateOutlet`.

**target.component.html**

```html
<ng-template #defaultTemplate></ng-template>
<ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="hmConfig.sourceTemplate || defaultTemplate">
    to be inserted here....
</ng-content>
```

There is no need of instantiating a `ContentChild`.

**target.component.js**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-target',
    templateUrl: './target.component.html'
})
export class TargetComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    private _config: Config;

    @Input()
    get hmConfig(): Config {
        return this._config;
    }
    set hmConfig(v: Config) {
        this._config = v;
        if (v.sourceTemplate && this.targetContainer) {
            this.targetContainer.createEmbeddedView(v.sourceTemplate);
        }
    }

    @ContentChild('target') targetContainer;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // output: After Modal view init: undefined
        console.log('After Modal view init: ', this.targetContainer);
    }

}
```